# Check T date folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

I want to check, If  T dated folder with formate 310114 is present in directory c:\Users\abc\Desktop.If T dated folder is present then output should come as Yes else No. for that I am using below query

```
     @echo off
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /T') do set year=%%c
    for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /T') do set month=%%a
    for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /T') do set day=%%b
    Set year1=%year:~2,4%
    set TODAY=%day%%month%%year1%
    for /F "tokens=1" %%a IN ('Dir "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\*%TODAY%*"  /-C/S/A:-D 2^>nul') Do Set y=!n2! & Set n2=%%a 
    echo %y%
    if %y% gtr 0 ( echo yes) else (echo no)
```

But it is not working, Even though T dated Folder is not there output is comming as 4.
Also echo %y% gives value as Volume. Why it is giving Volumn as output if file is not there, cant it give 0 as output?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your for loop, why not just use the an `if exist` statement?

```
if exist "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\*%TODAY%*" ( echo yes ) else echo no
```

Answer (score 0):

Using date /t gives results that are unreliable and change by region and settings.

The first four lines of this code will give you reliable YY DD MM YYYY HH Min Sec variables in XP Pro and higher.

This also uses the test suggested by unclemeat.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set "today=%DD%%MM%%YYYY%"

if exist "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\*%TODAY%*" (echo yes) else (echo no)

pause
```